# orderby nested linq

Tags: linq, nested, sql-order-by

```
var query = from m in db.Members.Include("Companies.Projects.Experiences.ExperienceTags")
                    where m.MemberId == id                        
                    select m;
```

I would like to also from this query to orderby the project.enddate. How would I do that. Also enddate can be null which then I would like it to be today date when it orderby. And, a company might not always have a project either which then it should be orderby today date too.

here is a image of the ef data diagram [a link](http://www3.telus.net/vanzoo/efdb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a many relationship you need to do a SelectMany like so:

```
var query = from m in db.Members.Include("Companies.Projects.Experiences.ExperienceTags")
            where m.MemberId == id
            orderby m.Companies.SelectMany(c => c.Projects).OrderByDescending(p => p.EndDate).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 
              DateTime.Today : 
              m.Companies.SelectMany(c => c.Projects).OrderByDescending(p => p.EndDate).FirstOrDefault()          
            select m;
```

Comment: This just make it return the member, it doesn't include any companies at all. I want it to include companies under the member.

Comment: @Prez - I removed the Let statement, that should keep the include statements

Comment: That seem to get all the records but doesn't do any order at all.